# UWP/C#/IoT/RPi: Access USB Device (Stick) from Win IoT on RPi AND Copy to KnownFolders

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi, iot, windows-10-iot-core

Here is my challenge:

- Windows IoT on Raspi, C# UWP-App
- On Boot or klick...

  - Enumerate connected USB devices
  - Select the USB Stick
  - Enumerate Fiels and folders on the stick
  - If a certain folder name is found, copy folder as-is to KnownFolders.Documents

It is astonishing that there are many half solutions on the web but none of them hardly works.

Some things I tried:

```
var removableDeviceList = await KnownFolders.RemovableDevices.GetFoldersAsync();
            if (removableDeviceList.Count > 0)
            {
                StorageFolder targetDevice = removableDeviceList.FirstOrDefault();
                ListBox.Items.Add(targetDevice.Name);
}
```

Works so far but stuck afterwards.

And yes, functions like Picture library, file definitions, removable devices are activated in the manifest.  I can't believe that this basic thing is really such a difficult task to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example I test on Raspberry Pi 3 with Windows 10 IoT Core. It works for me.

**Source folder**: test folder in USB drive root(E:\test). There are three files: hello.txt, welcome1.png, welcome3.jpg .

**Destination folder**: KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary root folder.

The following code complete copy files in test folder to KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary root folder.

```
   public async void USBDriveCopyFolder()
    {
        var targetFolderName = "test";

        var removableDevice = (await KnownFolders.RemovableDevices.GetFoldersAsync()).FirstOrDefault();
        if (null == removableDevice)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("removableDevice is null !");
            return;
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(removableDevice.Name + ":\n");

        var sourceFolder = await removableDevice.GetFolderAsync(targetFolderName);
        if (null == sourceFolder)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(targetFolderName + " folder is not found !");
            return;
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sourceFolder.Name + ":\n");

        var destFodler = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;
        if (null == destFodler)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary folder get failed !");
            return;
        }

        var files = await sourceFolder.GetFilesAsync();

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(file.Name + "\n");
            await file.CopyAsync(destFodler);
        }

    }
```

Device capabilities in package.appxmanifest:

```
  <Applications>

    ...
    ...

    <Application>
      <Extensions>
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
          <uap:FileTypeAssociation Name="txt">
            <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
              <uap:FileType>.txt</uap:FileType>
            </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
          </uap:FileTypeAssociation>
        </uap:Extension>
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
          <uap:FileTypeAssociation Name="jpg">
            <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
              <uap:FileType>.jpg</uap:FileType>
            </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
          </uap:FileTypeAssociation>
        </uap:Extension>
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
          <uap:FileTypeAssociation Name="png">
            <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
              <uap:FileType>.png</uap:FileType>
            </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
          </uap:FileTypeAssociation>
        </uap:Extension>
      </Extensions>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
  <Capabilities>
    <uap:Capability Name="picturesLibrary" />
    <uap:Capability Name="removableStorage" />
    <uap:Capability Name="documentsLibrary" />
  </Capabilities>
```

Comment: Works like a charm.

Comment: In that specific case don't forget to add <uap:Capability Name="documentsLibrary" /> to the capabilities as shown above (cannot be clicked directly in the UI version of the appxmanifest, use right click and "source code"